# Unable to connect to proxy, git

Tags: networking, proxy, git

I set a system wide proxy for on my machine through network settings, the proxy was localhost:9191 (I was using Burpsuite). I now have disabled the said proxy. And when I tried to clone a git repository through git clone "url", it gives an error `unable to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9191`. But I disabled the proxy! can anyone help? I restarted the `network-manager` but still dosen't seem to work.  I tried changing the Port for the proxy as well, and even after changing the port to say 80, the error I get is still `can't connect to localhost port 9191`

Comment: I tried using the `requests` module from python to connect to an external server and the same error persists. However the `wget` command seems to work fine.

Comment: How did you disable the proxy?  Did you deconfigure the proxy options in your `git` repositories/configurations, and your shell?

Comment: I just went to network settings again, and there was disable radio button for the proxy, I checked it that's it. @ThomasWard

Comment: The problem only seems to be for my unprivileged account. The root is able to connect to the network just fine. I'll try and copy it's setting to my account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried disabling the proxy through the GUI and that didn't work, so I decided to list my proxy settings through 
`env | grep -i proxy`

the output for the following was

```
HTTP_PROXY=localhost:9191
FTP_PROXY=localhost:9191
https_proxy=localhost:9191
.....
```

I tried the following command to empty those variables 
`export HTTP_PROXY=`
with all the variables done, the proxy settings are back to normal.